# Azure networking feature for restricted destination IP is not working

Tags: azure, feature-selection, firewall-rules

Azure networking feature is not working. I wanted to restrict that one machine to communicate with another specific machine only, I mentioned the destination IP address in inbound rule but it gets connected with another machine too.

I created a firewall rule against the specific destination IP address to be communicated with the machine on specific port but it was getting connected from non-specified destination IP address.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to have it connected to a single target machine, you should add an outbound rule allowing the connection deny the rest as the next priority.